# Real time Cross Correlation...?

Tags: signal-processing

I saw the one of your Answer that dated the 13th May 2015, i want to cross- correlate the vibration signal (with Predefined Signal) to remove the unwanted signals.But i want to do that real time so can we use the Arduino or have to use the Another platform. please advise .

Kaveendra Sampath

Comment: What answer? Link please. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You will have to be **a lot** more specific if you want any kind of useful answer. What type of Arduino? Sampling rate? Length of the reference signal? What does that reference signal look like? What information do you want to extract from the cross-correlation?

Comment: Please add more details to your question. It is not really answerable as you've written it.

Comment: The way worded your question only allows for this type of answer: "If you are only cross correlating a few bytes then you might be able to use an Aruduino Uno at low sampling speeds.  If you want to do more then you need a more powerful Arduino like a Intel Galileo."